# Question regarding the energy computation of the Ising-Spin Model

Tags: python, algorithms, monte-carlo

In most of the Monte-Carlo-Algorithms I studied, I found, at the place where they compute the energy, always a line of code, where they divided by four.

For example, this code-snippet is taken from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503761/ising-model-2d-python)

```py
def Energy(Q):
        starting_energy=0
        for i in range(len(Q)):
            for j in range(len(Q)):
                g=Q[i,j]
                n_y=Q[(i+1)%num,j]+Q[i,(j+1)%num]+Q[(i-1)%num,j]+Q[i,(j-1)%num]
                starting_energy+=g*-n_y
        return starting_energy/4
```

Another example can be found [here](https://rajeshrinet.github.io/blog/2014/ising-model/)

```py
def calcEnergy(config):
    '''Energy of a given configuration'''
    energy = 0
    for i in range(len(config)):
        for j in range(len(config)):
            S = config[i,j]
            nb = config[(i+1)%N, j] + config[i,(j+1)%N] + config[(i-1)%N, j] + config[i,(j-1)%N]
            energy += -nb*S
    return energy/4.
```

From my understanding, we want to compute the energy of a spin-configuration that includes the spin we are currently looking at plus its closest neighbors.
So in sum that would make 5 ising-spins we are computing in this function.

So why is it correct to return `return energy/4` instead of `return energy/5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The energy expression is not a sum over *spins*, it is a sum over *spin pairs*, each pair counted once. But as expressed in

```
nb = config[(i+1)%N, j] + config[i,(j+1)%N] + config[(i-1)%N, j] + config[i,(j-1)%N
```

each (non-zero coupling) spin pair is counted 4 times. Hence the need to quarter the final result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't understand that it is actually spin pairs one is looking at.